# ng-model for complicated JSON structure

Tags: angularjs, json

my application has a side navigation bar that pulls info from the content in the template based on ng-models.i am unable to figure out what should my ng-model be for 'meaning.'
the foll is my JSON:

```
{
    "expression": "mithrandir",
    "meaning": [
    {
    "m": "language of the elves",
    "e": ""
    }
    ],
    "example": ["mithrandir is cool"],
    "pronunciation": "",
    "notes": "",
    "meta": {
    "book": "There and back again",
    "author": "Frodo Baggins",
    "tags": ["middle earth", "elves"]}
    },
```

I am iterating over the 'meaning' array. Data is comin thru all right from the JSON file.

```
<ul> 
<li ng-repeat="matlab in classified.meaning">{{ matlab.m }}: {{ matlab.e }}</li>
</ul>
```

However, the 'meaning' is not flowing into the side-navigation.

The foll is the code and the rendition:

```
<md-input-container>
                    <label for="meaning">Meaning</label>
                    <textarea type="text" id="meaning" ng-model="classified.meaning.matlab.m" ng-list></textarea>
</md-input-container>
```

[Side navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnMed.png)

I know i am getting the ng-model against the 'meaning' wrong? Id appreciate your inputs in helpin me figure out. thanks

Comment: Your code must works fine, did you check your object in your view? {{classified}}

Comment: yeah.. im just concerend that the content for 'meaning' is not being dispalyed in the side navigation. apart from that everythin works all right.

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul> 
<li ng-repeat="matlab in classified.meaning">{{ matlab.m }}: {{ matlab.e }}    </li>
</ul>
```

That code will work fine, since you are iterating over an array. You can call each element 'matlab' or 'foo' or whatever

The following code will not, since there is no 'matlab' object in classified.meaning, which keeps being an array

```
<textarea type="text" id="meaning" ng-model="classified.meaning.matlab.m" ng-list></textarea>
```

Comment: so what shld my ng-model be?

Comment: try this

 <textarea type="text" id="meaning" ng-model="classified.meaning[0].m"></textarea>

Comment: @Romeu i am incorprated your suggestion, but its not quite rendering right. the pre tag dispalys it as follows: {
  "expression": "mithrandir",
  "meaning": [
    {
      "m": [
        "elves speak this language"
      ],
      "e": ""
    }
  ],

Comment: the way my JSON is structured is as follows: {
 "expression": "to the day",
 "meaning": [
 {
 "m": "",
 "e": ""
 }
 ],

Comment: then classified.meaning[0].m[0]

- It's just accesing a js array

Comment: I removed the ng-list from the textarea tag cause it didn't handle it. Did you do the same?
What do you see if you display {{classified.meaning[0]}} ?